# Typescript: instanceof check doesn't smart cast

Tags: node.js, typescript, casting, return, instanceof

I have an event listener callback like so:

```
function(ev: Event) {
    var userBox = id("user-box");
    var target = ev.target;
    // here
}
```

Now, I need to cast target to Element.
Why does this compile:

```
function(ev: Event) {
    var userBox = id("user-box");
    var target = ev.target;
    if (target instanceof Element) {
        if (userBox.contains(target)) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

... but this doesn't?

```
function(ev: Event) {
    var userBox = id("user-box");
    var target = ev.target;
    if (target !instanceof Element) {
        return;
    }
    if (userBox.contains(target)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it's a syntax error (in JavaScript) or the non-`null` assertion operator (in TypeScript). `instanceof` is an *infix operator*, it expects its operands to be on its left and right. You need `if (!(target instanceof Element))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`variable instanceof XYZ` is a single operation that yields a `boolean` value. It can be inverted by adding parenthesis: `!(target instanceof Element)`. When you do `target! instanceof Element`, you are invoking the non-null assertion operator in TypeScript on `target`, which is a compile-time assertion.

E.g.

```
function(ev: Event) {
    var userBox = id("user-box");
    var target = ev.target;
    if (!(target instanceof Element)) {
        return;
    }
    if (userBox.contains(target)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good point about the TypeScript aspect of this question and why it's not a syntax error!

Comment: T.J. Crowder just commented this under the main post, thank you guys! Will mark this as solved in 9 minutes.

Comment: @julkali - Yeah, but concision pointed out why you weren't getting a syntax error. I kind of forgot at first that you were using TypeScript. :-D